# Exporting android application in eclipse CRASH?

Tags: android

I have my application already on playstore , I developed new project with same package name , when I try to export it with the same keystore file , Eclipse CRASH .. but If I export with new keystore , it works fine ... I need to export it with old keystore so I'll be able to update it on Play store

Comment: Does it actually crash? Or does it put up an error message?

Comment: yes its crash and close

Comment: Under `Project` uncheck `Build Automatically`, then close and relaunch eclipse, `Clear Project` and try exporting again.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try command line tools to build apk for release. use 'ant release'.
see google's [guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html)